# CSS property change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have css like this:

```
.cls .imageX
{
  float:left;
}

.cls .imageY
{
  float:right;
}
```

it is being used in a page like this:

```
<div class="cls">
<a href="" class="imageX"><img src="left.png"/></a>
<a href="" class="imageY"><img src="right.png"/></a>
</div>
```

I don't have the site's source code. I see this source via firebug and I have to write JS code to change it via onload event. That is my job. Now I would like it to become:

```
<div class="cls">
<a href="" class="imageX"><img src="right.png"/></a>
<a href="" class="imageY"><img src="left.png"/></a>
</div>
```

There are two ways I think I may be able to resolve this but sadly none work for me at all

```
1>  $('.cls .imageX img').attr('src','right.png');
    $('.cls .imageY img').attr('src','left.png');

2>  $('.cls .imageX').css('float','right'); 
    $('.cls .imageY').css('float','left');
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? Just setting the `img` after `.imageX` to `right.png`?

Comment: What happens when you try the first way? Is actually it in an `onload` function?

Comment: For example my images now are |>  and  <| but I would like to change them into  <| and |> (arrow left and right button images)

Comment: @TomSmilack, nothing happens, it is just all the same

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 that you provide...seems to work. `alert($('.cls .imageX img').attr('src', 'right.png').attr('src'));​`Checkout my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MYDNv/

Comment: Thank you, this is strange. The two images are located to control image sliding, and it looks like it is repeatedly reinitialized but I can't find where the source for the image slider because my firefox keeps crashing 80/100 times

Comment: Try switching to chrome for debugging javascript. Its awesome. I struggled for few hours to get used to chrome. But now I rarely use firebug